# Maven not installing aws-encryption-sdk-java dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, aws-java-sdk, maven-dependency

maven noob here

I have this in my `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-encryption-sdk-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but for some  reason, when I do `mvn dependency:resolve`, this will never show up in the list, and the code itself is forever failing to `import com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk`. Also the jar file wouldn't appear under `External Libraries` in IntelliJ.

If my googling skills haven't filed me, isn't `mvn dependency:resolve` suppose to download the jar file? Please let me know what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce, [see the screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/8suRaAM.png). What error do you get if you run `mvn clean package` in the command line?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Actually it shows under `mvn dependency:resolve` now once I got off VPN. But it's still not imported properly. When I `mvn clean build` it builds successfully without error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which repositories are you connecting to?
Are you connecting to nexus/artifactory/... which in its turn cannot download the dependency?
You can check the repositories in the settings.xml (usually in a .m2 folder).
If using nexus/artifactory/... please check in the respective application if something fails

Are you behind some kind of proxy server?

You can check additional logging output by adding one of following flags to the command:

```
-e, --errors  (Produce execution error messages)
-X, --debug (Produce execution debug output)
```

I commonly use `mvn clean install`

Comment: I'm using artifactory, and I think I've already modified the `settings.xml` to what it needs to be.
I've tried changing some vpn settings, ans now seems like it's showing up when I do `mvn dependency:resolve`, however it's still not in `External Libraries` nor can be imported. When I `mvn clean install` it never shows any error message (except for the tests failing probably cause of the missing dependency).

Comment: In intellij you can try to reimport the maven project now that the dependency has been downloaded?

Comment: That worked!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!! That was totally me being a noob lol.